# Чем заменить `WITH RECURISVE` в триггере?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlite3

У меня имеется следующая таблица (рис. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6HLa.png)), и мне надо поддерживать правильные значения для поля `price` у категорий (`is_category = 1`), которые для них вычисляются как средняя цена всех ее товаров, включая товары дочерних категорий.

[image]

Для этого я первоначально создал следующие триггеры, которые работают, но вычисляют неправильные значения уже для категорий второго уровня (например, «Товары»), так как считают среднее от цен категорий-потомков, а не от товаров:

```sql
pragma recursive_triggers=ON;
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_price_insert
AFTER INSERT ON shop_units WHEN NEW.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND NEW.is_category = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        shop_units
    SET
        price = (SELECT AVG(price) FROM shop_units WHERE parent_id = NEW.parent_id)
    WHERE
        id = NEW.parent_id;
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_price_update
AFTER UPDATE OF price ON shop_units WHEN NEW.parent_id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        shop_units
    SET
        price = (SELECT AVG(price) FROM shop_units WHERE parent_id = NEW.parent_id)
    WHERE
        id = NEW.parent_id;
END;
```

Мне пришла идея использовать `WITH RECURSIVE` для того, чтобы рекурсивно собирать всех потомков, и я написал следующий код, который должен вычислять правильные значения:

```
...
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_price_insert
AFTER INSERT ON shop_units WHEN NEW.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND NEW.is_category = 0
BEGIN
WITH RECURSIVE
    child_ids(identifier) AS (
        SELECT NEW.parent_id
        UNION
        SELECT
            id
        FROM
            shop_units, child_ids
        WHERE
            shop_units.parent_id=child_ids.identifier
    )
UPDATE
    shop_units
SET
    price = (SELECT AVG(price) AS price FROM shop_units INNER JOIN child_ids ON shop_units.id = child_ids.identifier WHERE is_category = 0)
WHERE
    id = NEW.parent_id;
END;
...
```

Но который не работает из-за того, что `WITH` запрещен в триггерах.
Я долго думал и гуглил, но так и не смог придумать, как переписать этот триггер, чтобы он считал все корректно.
Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если надо хранить иерархические данные и значимо выполнять иерархические запросы, то использовать parent-child как минимум глупо. Измените лучше схему хранения данных. Для именно озвученной задачи хорошо подойдёт хранение полного характеристического пути узла.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370761/sqlite-loop-statements если я верно вас понял, то первый же ответ ```sqlite> PRAGMA recursive_triggers = on;```

Comment: нет @ВладимирКлыков вы неправильно поняли. `recursive_triggers` влияет на то, будет ли срабатывать триггер для модифицирующих операций выполненых при срабатывании триггера. Это не имеет отношения к рекурсивным СТЕ

Comment: @Akina, вы имеете ввиду под «хранением полного характеристического пути узла» хранение для каждого узла информации о всех его потомках?

Comment: Наоборот - хранение полного пути к узлу от корня. Тогда для любого потомка путь любого его родителя есть подстрока с первой позиции.